# Git branching on a MVC project - 2 or more views with shared core

Tags: git, model-view-controller, git-branch

I'm starting to learn git branching, and I'm developing with other people a web based MVC project (using Zend).

We just worked on the master branch since today; now we need to develop tow different views (html aspect, css & co.), so we created a branch, let's call it *newview*.

Obviously we keep developing models and controllers, which have to be the same for the two branches.

In a few days from now, we'd like to merge the code changes from models and controllers from the branch *master* to the branch *newview*.

So the question is: how to merge only the models and controllers code from branch master to branch newview without overwriting/merging the code for the view (which have to remain separate)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for subtree merges:

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/using-merge-subtree.html

The free online [Pro Git Book has a chapter on Subtree Merging](http://progit.org/book/ch6-7.html)